# addActionListener(other Class)

Tags: java, jbutton

I have a class PanelLogiciel ( a cardLayout to show interface for connexion or interface for the market) and the Class PanelAcces(interface for connection):
I would like to use an ActionListener on a JButton from PanelAcces,if you use the JButton,PanelLogiciel will change from PanelAcces to another JPanel with the CardLayout. Hope you can help and sorry if it's a stupid question but can't find ...

```
package e_commerce;

import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class PanelLogiciel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    CardLayout diaporama = new CardLayout();
    PanelAcces panelAcces;
    PanelSite panelSite;
    String connexion = new String("connexion");
    String site = new String("site");
    Connection connexBD;
    public PanelLogiciel(){
        this.setLayout(diaporama);
        panelAcces = new PanelAcces(this);
        panelSite = new PanelSite();
        //PanelProduit panelProduit = new PanelProduit();
        //PanelPanier panelPanier = new PanelPanier();


        //this.add(panelProduit);
        //this.add(panelPanier);
        this.add(panelAcces,connexion);
        this.add(panelSite,site);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent parEvt){
        Object source = parEvt.getSource();
        if (source == panelAcces.boutonConnexion){
            try {
                if (SQL.methodeConnexion(connexBD, panelAcces.entrerIdentifiant.getText(), panelAcces.entrerMotDePasse.getText()) == 0){
                    System.out.println("cc");
                    diaporama.show(panelSite,site); 
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("marche ap");
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the Class PanelAcces(interface for connection):

```
package e_commerce;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class PanelAcces extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
    JLabel labelIdentifiant; //= new JLabel("Identifiant:");
    JTextField entrerIdentifiant; //= new JTextArea();
    JLabel labelMotDePasse; //= new JLabel("Mot de passe:");
    JTextField entrerMotDePasse; //= new JTextArea();
    JButton boutonConnexion = new JButton("Connexion");
    PanelLogiciel panelLogiciel;


    public PanelAcces(PanelLogiciel parLogiciel){
        panelLogiciel = parLogiciel;
        labelIdentifiant = new JLabel("Identifiant:");
        entrerIdentifiant = new JTextField(10);
        labelMotDePasse = new JLabel("Mot de passe:");
        entrerMotDePasse = new JTextField(10);

        this.add(labelIdentifiant);
        this.add(entrerIdentifiant);
        //entrerIdentifiant.addActionListener(this);
        this.add(labelMotDePasse);
        this.add(entrerMotDePasse);
        //entrerMotDePasse.addActionListener(this);
        this.add(boutonConnexion);
        boutonConnexion.addActionListener(panelLogiciel);

    }


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent parEvt) {
        Object source = parEvt.getSource();
        if (source == boutonConnexion){
            System.out.println("beub");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Do not implement the ActionListener in your Panael class. Implement it as an extra class

Comment: @Jens  sorry but i think i didn't understand what you tried to say,i must create a new class just for the listener?How it will helps, my class PanelLogiciel will still need that listener

Comment: Yes you should create a new Class for the listener. You can add it than also to your panel